# How to emulate function members in Python 3.x?

Tags: python-3.x

I am right now in the middle of the implementation of a Python 3.7 class (let us call it `C`) and I have a bunch of function members (let us denote them as `f1`, `f2`, ...) which actually behave in much the same way, i.e., they prepare some data and then they invoke another service provided by the same class.

These functions could be implemented separately within class `C` with `def f1(self, ...)`, `def f2(self, ...)` and such but I was wondering whether it is possible to implement a unique accessor ---let us denote it `__function__ (self, args)`--- such that the first argument would be the function to invoke (either `f1`, `f2`, etc.) and next the arguments to it. This way, a unique implementation of such `__function__` would allow the implementation of a bunch of rather similar function members.

Indeed, `__call__ (self, ...)` apparently does the job, but it is not exactly what I am looking for as implementing it would then make the caller to provide the statement: `c (f1, ...)`, `c (f2, ...)` and such (with `c` an instance of `C`) whereas I'd like the call to be `c.f1(...)`, `c.f2 (...)` but all these implemented simultaneously within the same method in `C`.

Another idea I already tried (and pointed out by Primusa in the comments) is to overload `__getattr__` as follows:

```py
    def __getattr__ (self, key):
        """executes the function named by 'key' with no parameters in this
           configuration file and returns the resulting context

        """

        command = """{0}.{1} ()""".format (self._namespace, key)
        return self.execute (command)
```

This way, statements such as `c.f1` are executed through `__getattr__` but this does not allow passing arguments. What if I have a function `f2` which takes, e.g., two arguments?

This is all just for the sake of curiosity, I do not mind how involved the answer might be as in the end I'd most likely implement all those `f` functions by hand one by one but as Donald Knuth said once: "if a programmer has to do something twice, he creates a script"

Thanks a lot for your help,

Comment: You could override `__getattr__`. But regardless you'd still have to write out what happens in each function.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Primusa for your reply. That is what I actually did but that solution does not allow passing arguments. Right now I have def `__getattr__ (self, key)` where `key` is then used as the function name to emulate (and so far invocations look like `c.key` but how to pass parameters?

Comment: you should post your code, but right now i'm assuming that your `__getattr__` isn't returning the function object and is instead returning a result after calling the function

Comment: That's absolutely right! I'm editing my question right now ... (I never thought actually of returning the function ... !!)

Comment: Maybe I'm interpreting this question wrong, but would [decorators](https://realpython.com/primer-on-python-decorators/) work for your use case?

Comment: Thanks a lot delyeet for your comment! I actually know nothing about them, but I will actually go over your link. Thanks a lot!!